Evaluating the derivative of $(1+x^t)^l$ in 0
I'm trying to evaluate $k$-derivative of the polynomial $(1+x^t)^l$. Here what I've done
$$
\frac{d^k}{dx^k}((1+x^t)^l) = \sum\limits_{i \geq \frac{k}{t}}^{l}\binom{l}{i}(ti)_kx^{ti-k},
$$
where $(ti)_k = ti(ti-1)(ti-2)\ldots(ti-k+1)$. Now I'm trying to evaluate this derivative in 0 point, i.e. evaluate the sum
$$
\sum\limits_{i \geq \frac{k}{t}}^{l}\binom{l}{i}(ti)_k.
$$
I'm trying to use Stirling numbers of the first kind $(ti)_k = \sum\limits_{m}^{k}s(k,m)(ti)^m$, but this doesn't help to get something.
Has anyone encountered formulas of this kind? Can they be calculated or are there any non-trivial estimations?
